# Askubuntu.com is really slow over HTTPS?

Tags: support

I've never used meta before but my understanding is that questions about the site go here?

Normally when I log into Askubuntu it uses http, but today when I logged in it used https, and it's unbearably slow. I can access the site both ways after logging in, and http is instantaneous at loading pages while https takes maybe 20 seconds to load a page if at all. Is anyone else having this problem? I would assume I'm supposed to be using https to secure my account.

Comment: Yes i can confirm this, the most time when i try to login today it loads about 20 seconds then i get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier, Stack Exchange was moving all operations from New York to Oregon, which caused slowness in all HTTPS connections. This can be seen in [the twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/472841950216065025):

> Slow HTTP Connectivity - May 31, 2014 - After our move to the Oregon data center we are experiencing issues... http://tmblr.co/Z7Lcqt1HQvpQV

If you want more information, check the tumblr link.